# Export Excel 2010 in JavaScript using Apache POI library

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I already have a java application which exports some data into an *Excel 2003* dataformat and I would like to get it exported into *Excel 2010* by *using org.apache.poi library*. Is it possible to do it using java?

Comment: In the question title, you wrote "JavaScript" but the in the question, you ask about Java

Answer (score 1):

An [example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/BusinessPlan.java) from the apache poi site.
Creating the workbook

```
//Excel 2003
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
//Excel 2010 and upwords
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

Saving the workbook as a .xls or the new .xlsx

```
// Write the output to a file
String file = "foo.xls";
if(wb instanceof XSSFWorkbook) file += "x";
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
wb.write(out);
out.close();
```